# How to use value from Seekbar value?

Tags: java, android

The code works fine but the seekbar value is not fetched in my code. The error shown is "Cannot resolve symbol progress" even after making it public. Someone throw light on this possibly with short explanation. I have stored the SeekBar value in progress and tried to use it in calculation further.

```
        sb = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.set_years);
        yrs = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.years);

        sb.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            public int progress;
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
                progress = i;
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                yrs.setText(progress+" year(s)");

            }
        });

        addButtonClickListener();
    }

    private void addButtonClickListener() {

        submit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);
        submit.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        float loanAmtValue = 0;
        float roiValue = 0;
        double answer;

        loanAmt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.amt);
        loanAmtValue = Float.parseFloat(loanAmt.getText().toString());
        roi = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.roi);
        roiValue = Float.parseFloat(roi.getText().toString());

        if (loanAmtValue != 0 || roiValue != 0){

            answer = (loanAmtValue * roiValue * progress) / 100;

            siResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
            siResult.setText("Calculated Simple Interest for Amount Rs" + loanAmtValue + " and ROI " + roiValue + "% is = " + Double.toString(answer));

            loanAmt.setText("0");
            roi.setText("0");
        }
        else
        {
            siResult.setText("Please provide valid details");
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all - your `progress` variable is member of `SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener` anonymous inner class. You cannot access it directly without having reference to instance of this listener.

Second of all - you do not need to store the progress by yourself. Use `sb.getProgress();`.

Comment: Done...thanks fr making it clear..
And 1 more doubt..wen I do not enter any value in d field d app crashes..Lyk in PHP der is sumthin if isset() function to check values are present or not...is der sumthin lyk dat in android(java)??

Comment: Check if `value != null`.

Comment: Its not happening ..Operator != cannot be applied to 'float' 'null'
This is error...

Comment: Try to be more specific about "app crashes".

Comment: I dint run d app..since it had dat error wich i have written it in my previous comment..

Comment: I am referring to your first comment. `float` or `int` (not `Float` or `Integer`) is always set, as default to 0 (while `Float` and `Integer` can be null). Since result type of sb.getProgress is `int` the reason of crash is somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Check your imports for the error "Cannot resolve symbol progress".
and check too, if  you define the max for seekbar.